# wp_head makes my custom page template not work in Customizer?

Tags: php, customization, theme-customizer

I have a weird issue where if I am in the Customizer and visit a page which uses a custom page template I made it doesn't load the site in the preview. But I can see that it loads in the console.
I found out that the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` was the issue. If I remove this part in the site template PHP file it loads just fine. But of course it doesn't look or work right.

I use `<?php wp_head(); ?>` and `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` because the rest of the theme uses a different header and footer, so I don't want to call `get_footer` and `get_header` (also this doesn't solve the problem I am having).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have anything custom hooked into wp_head on that template?

Comment: Nothing, just searched through my complete theme folder.

Comment: Scripts are enqueued on wp_head remember.

Comment: Tried removing all the enqueue scripts from the theme, no change.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this way:

```
<?php get_header('your_custom_header');?>
<?php get_footer('your_custom_footer');?>
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?